# uninstall image viewer

Tags: image-viewers

In Ubuntu 17.04, image viewer suddenly does not want to display images anymore. It opens the file, but shows a blank screen, with black flickers when moving the mouse. All other programs are working fine (GIMP, inkscape, etc).

As image viewer came with the ubuntu installation I cannot find the package name to uninstall it and reinstall. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package name for the default image viewer, is `eog`.

Answer (score 4):

You can uninstall Image Viewer (whose name in the GNOME project is  [Eye of Gnome](https://help.gnome.org/users/eog/stable/), aka EOG), with this command:

```
sudo apt purge eog
```

Comment: kept refusing to acknowledge the mosue drop window X button. Did not respond to xkill. removed as above. now using gwenview or gimp